# How to schedule method invoking at 04:00 every day in ASP .NET MVC 5.1 without 3rd party libriaries?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, scheduled-tasks, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have a method

```
public void SendReports(){refering to Entity Framework database and sending some records via mail}
```

I would like to invoke this method everyday at 04:00. Is there any solution built in ASP .NET MVC 5.1 to achieve that? I can't find any info about it but it seems pretty common thing people would demand.

WebApplication will be deployed to Microsoft Azure.

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7

Comment: It would be completely unreliable to do that in ASP.NET alone, because of app pool recycling.

Comment: Why not compile it into an executable and put it in a scheduled task?

Comment: I know that you said without third party libraries, but Hangfire is just too good to ignore.. http://hangfire.io/

Comment: I think you need to create new console application. Create same method like 'SendReports()' in Main class. After you built this application , it will generate executable file for you. You need to create windows scheduler task for this executable file. I think this is best option.

Comment: @Lashane It is ASP .NET MVC application problem not desktop.

Comment: @Hiren There is ASP.NET MVC 5.1 tag it has nothing to do with desktop programming.

Comment: @yoda Yes and we are telling you ASP.NET MVC 5.1 Can't (without a ton of work, enough work that it would be considered a "library") do what you want to do. You need to run a service.

Comment: @Yoda I don't think it is possible. Will follow this question

Comment: IMO this question shouldn't be downvoted - it's a common problem and solutions are educational and usefull.

Answer (score 4):

This really isn't suppose to be done by ASP.NET engine.

Instead make a windows service(or an executable) that relies on some sort of messaging(MSMQ?) between ASP.NET engine and the windows service(or some sort of data in the database) that does this for you.

Pick the right guy for the job(Mafia style :-P)

Edit:

Azure? [Scheduler?](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/scheduler/)

And also the simplest I know on Windows Azure: [Web Jobs](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET can't do what you want to do by itself. The IIS AppPool your webiste is running under will shut itself down after a idle period so you don't know if your code will be running at 4:00 or not. You need a scheduled service outside of your ASP.NET site that triggers your code to run and is not dependant on your IIS AppPool running. You can create services that do exactly that in the azure portal under App Services->Scheduler.

[image]

What you will need to do is have a controller that when called will run `SendReports`. You then have the scheduled job in azure call the URL for that controller at 4:00 every day.

Comment: I'll do it next week when I will deploy the application. Will I be able to write a code there where I can do this : `var db = new ApplicationDbContext();` ? I want to read data from db insert it into excel sheet and send mail every day. I know how to do it in my ASP.NET MVC app without scheduling, it will be my first encounter with Azure.

Comment: @Yoda All the scheduler does is call a URL at a pre-defined time for you. You can do whatever you want inside the controller for that url, if you want to make a db context and write something to it go ahead and do it.

Comment: I think even WebJobs will be useful here